# show all git log for several git projects

Tags: git, repository

I want to travel several git projects which are managed by repo.
I'm not sure if there is any repo command can achieve this.

For example, here are work folders:
  `work/.repo/` 
  `work/folderA/.git/` 
  `work/folderB/.git/` 
If I want find key word "dummy" in git log in folderA & folder B, how to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think `git` alone can do this. You will most likely need to fashion a command-line script to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always try repo command :

```
repo forall project1 project2 -c git log
```

or you need to write a script which will run git commands in loop.